# R-INLA results: Why does the mean for my fixed effects equal the median?

Tags: r, bayesian, inla

I am building a Besag-York-Mollie model using a Poisson distribution to estimate the relative risk of infection for neighborhoods in California using R-INLA. I have areal data and my model is as follows:

```
full.formula <- cases ~ adultpov + f(re_u, model = "besag", 
                                     graph = g, 
                                     scale.model = TRUE) + 
                                   f(re_v, model = "iid")

res <- inla(full.formula, family = "poisson", 
                          data = map.inla, 
                          E = E, 
            control.compute = list(dic = TRUE, 
                                   waic = TRUE, 
                                   cpo = TRUE,
                                   return.marginals.predictor = TRUE),
            control.predictor = list(compute = TRUE))
```

where "adultpov" is my one covariate, re_u is the spatial residual variation, re_v is unstructured noise, and E is the expected number of cases. I use the default prior here but also tested the half-normal, half-cauchy, half-t, uniform, and PC priors.

I'm not having any issues with my model, I'm trying to understand the results. For my fixed effects, the mean for the intercept and covariate equals the median. I wasn't expecting that and am trying to understand how or why this is possible, given I don't have a normal distribution.

[image: Screenshot of the results summary]

Any ideas or recommendations? Am I doing something wrong? I noticed having the mean equal to the median is relatively common in the R-INLA tutorials, but I don't understand why. I expected the mean and the median to be at least slightly different.